# Can I use ifnull() in On clause of inner join?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, ifnull

I have 2 columns in  `Table1`: *email1* and *email2*. I need to fetch full name by concatenation of FirstName and LastName which are in some other table and it is associated with the above mentioned email fields. But I need to make sure, if email2 field is there then fetch the associated Name columns, if email2 field is null then fetch values associated with email1. So please advise how I can use ifnull() and to do the inner join? Here is the table structure:

Table1

- email1
- email2

Table2

- FirstName
- LastName
- email

Thanks in advance, Krishna

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  COALESCE(CONCAT(c.FirstName, ' ', c.LastName), CONCAT(b.FirstName, ' ', b.LastName)) FullName
FROM    table1 a
        LEFT JOIN table2 b
            ON a.email1 = b.email
        LEFT JOIN table2 c
            ON a.email2 = c.email
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2960e/1)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)